# How can I point upper folder when using express.static() in Express 4.0?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, directory

My angular & node app structure is like this.

```
MyApp/
----app/
--------components/
-----------angular js files(js,css)
----server/
--------server.js
----index.html
```

And I want to use  `express.static()` to set static files such as angular.js files or css files. but, I'm not sure how to point to upper folder when using `static(__dirname +'/app')`.

`__dirname` means current directory but I want to point upper directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
var path = require('path');
var dir = path.normalize(__dirname +'/../app');
```

from the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_p):

> Normalize a string path, taking care of '..' and '.' parts.
>
> When multiple slashes are found, they're replaced by a single one; when the path contains a trailing slash, it is preserved. On Windows backslashes are used.